# Subscribing/unsubscribing a static Action delegate from another class

Tags: c#, delegates

We code in Unity, but this is a general C# question.

We have a class with `static Action`'s. We subscribe to these Actions all over the app:

```
class Listeners{
    public static Action OnGameLoaded;
    public static Action OnAfterGameLoaded;
}
```

Now, we create objects from some class and we sometimes want to subscribe to `OnGameLoaded` in that class:

Current approach:

```
class Monster : MonoBehavior {

    // awake is like a constructor (called when the object is created)
    public override void Awake(){
      
        Listeners.OnGameLoaded -= OnGameLoaded; // for safety
        Listeners.OnGameLoaded += OnGameLoaded;
    }

    // OnDestroy is like a destructor (called when the object is destroyed)
    public override void OnDestroy(){
        Listeners.OnGameLoaded -= OnGameLoaded;
    }

    private void OnGameLoaded(){
        ...
    }

}
```

Now, this has been painful for years cause for every class we write, for every `Action` we want to subscribe to, we have to write a dedicated `-=`, `+=` and another `-=` in `OnDestroy`. We're trying to optimize this.

The ideal scenario for us would be something like:

```
class Monster : SomeSuperclass {
    
     
    public override void Awake(){
        
        Subscribe(Listeners.OnGameLoaded, OnGameLoaded);
    }
    
    private void OnGameLoaded(){
        ...
    }

    // and that's it, forget about OnDestroy
}
```

I tried making a `Base Class` in between `Monster` and `MonoBehavior` so it will handle subscribing and unsubscribing in `OnDestroy()`, and of course keep track of these `Action`'s. Here's that base class approach:

```
class BaseClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<Action, Action> actions = new Dictionary<Action, Action>();

    protected void Subscribe(ref Action action, Action function)
    {
        action += function;
        actions.Add(action, function);
    }

    public virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        // unsubscribe
        foreach(KeyValuePair<Action, Action> entry in actions)
        {
            Action action = entry.Key;
            action -= entry.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

But after hours and hours of debugging, it turns out `Action` is getting copied once it's passed to a function so we end up keeping track of different actions and we can't unregister them in the end.

Do you guys have any idea how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `+=` operator on an action combines the two actions and then **assigns the result back to the left-hand-side operand**, so to do this operation inside another method, you need to pass the action as `ref`, which you've done.

The problem then is that you need to unsubscribe it at some point in the future, which means using the `-=` operator and somehow making sure that result gets assigned back to the property in the `Listener` class, and not the local function variable where you're performing the operation.

As far as I know, it's not possible to store a `ref` parameter and write to it later.

One option would be to use unsafe/pointers, but I haven't worked with those much in C# so I'll let someone else describe that process (and how to ensure it doesn't blow up in your face).

Another option would be to wrap each action from `Listener` into a wrapper object, and pass that object around. You can then assign the action inside that wrapper class whenever you need.

Note that if you don't have control over the `Listener` class, I can't think of any good solutions. You'd be stuck with using pointers, or some magic with expression trees / reflection.

Something like below.

---

Action Wrapper:

```cs
public interface IActionWrapper {

    public void Subscribe(Delegate action);
    public void Unsubscribe(Delegate action);

}

public class ActionWrapper<T> : IActionWrapper where T: Delegate {

    public T? Action;

    public void Subscribe(Delegate action) {
        Action = (T?)Delegate.RemoveAll(Action, action);
        Action = (T?)Delegate.Combine(Action, action);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Delegate action) {
        Action = (T?)Delegate.RemoveAll(Action, action);
    }

}
```

Listener class:

```cs
public static class Listeners {

    public static ActionWrapper<Action> EventOne = new();
    public static ActionWrapper<Action<int>> EventTwo = new();
    public static ActionWrapper<Action<int, int>> EventThree = new();

}
```

And for your behaviour implementations:

```cs
public class Base {

    private Dictionary<IActionWrapper, Delegate> actions = new();

    protected void Subscribe<T>(ActionWrapper<T> action, T function) where T: Delegate {
        action.Subscribe(function);
        actions.Add(action, function);
    }

    public virtual void OnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe
        foreach (KeyValuePair<IActionWrapper, Delegate> entry in actions) {
            IActionWrapper action = entry.Key;
            action.Unsubscribe(entry.Value);
        }
    }

}

public class Derived : Base {

    public string Name { get; }

    public Derived(string name) {
        Name = name;
        Subscribe(Listeners.EventOne, HandleEventOne);
        Subscribe(Listeners.EventTwo, HandleEventTwo);
        Subscribe(Listeners.EventThree, HandleEventTwo);
    }

    private void HandleEventOne() {
        Console.WriteLine("Event one handled in " + Name);
    }

    private void HandleEventTwo(int x) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Event two handled in {Name}. X = {x}");
    }

    private void HandleEventTwo(int x, int y) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Event three handled in {Name}. X = {x}, Y = {y}");
    }

}
```

Testing the implementation:

```cs
var derA = new Derived("DerA");
var derB = new Derived("DerB");

Listeners.EventOne.Action?.Invoke();
Listeners.EventTwo.Action?.Invoke(42);
Listeners.EventThree.Action?.Invoke(36, 81);

/* Outputs:
Event one handled in DerA
Event one handled in DerB
Event two handled in DerA. X = 42
Event two handled in DerB. X = 42
Event three handled in DerA. X = 36, Y = 81
Event three handled in DerB. X = 36, Y = 81
*/

Console.WriteLine("Destroying derA");
derA.OnDestroy();

Listeners.EventOne.Action?.Invoke();
Listeners.EventTwo.Action?.Invoke(42);
Listeners.EventThree.Action?.Invoke(36, 81);

/* Outputs:
Event one handled in DerB
Event two handled in DerB. X = 42
Event three handled in DerB. X = 36, Y = 81
 */
```

---

Note that this method will also work for `Func<...>`, though probably less useful because you can only get one of the return values out, no matter how many `Func`s you combine together.

The return value you get back from calling `Invoke(...)` on a combination of `Func`s will be the return value from the last `Func` added.

Comment: Honestly I didn't think that's possible. Works like a charm!

Comment: Do you have any idea @brads3290 how to add generic support to it, to support `Action<T>` and `Action<T,K>` ?

Comment: @Jacob I would add the generics to the wrapper class and simply use them on the wrapped property. You would need a different wrapper class for each number of generic parameters you want to support, I.e Wrapper<T> contains an Action<T> as the property, Wrapper<T,K> contains Action<T,K> as a property, etc.

Comment: Oh, and it would get a bit more messy with the subscribe method and storing the wrappers as well. You’d have to do some more overloading there. Lmk if you need a code example

Comment: Well @brads3290 I tried to write it just as you described (that was my initial idea) but I was completely stuck at the "Subscribe" side. I didn't know whether I should declare 3 separate dictionaries for Action, Action<T>, and Action<T,K> and I couldn't override these methods properly. I'd really use your help if you'd be kind enough :)

Comment: @Jacob I figured out a way to generalise it to any `Action<T1, ...Tn>` using `System.Delegate` (which `Action<...>` is derived from) and calling the `Combine` and `Remove` methods directly (which is what `+=`/`-=` does behind the scenes). I've updated my answer to use the more generalised code.

Comment: I love you man, thank you :)